# Deprecate barrel file

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to deprecate a barrel file in Dart?

I have renamed a barrel file in our package, but still want to keep a copy of the old barrel file so that users can get a deprecation message.

`util.dart`

```dart
@deprecated('Import math.dart instead, this file will be removed in a Flame '
            'v1.10.0')
export 'src/math/random_fallback.dart';
export 'src/math/solve_cubic.dart';
export 'src/math/solve_quadratic.dart';
```

This will result in:

> Annotation must be either a const variable reference or const constructor invocation. (Documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Deprecated` tag (capital D) for this to work:

```dart
@Deprecated('Import math.dart instead, this file will be removed in a Flame '
            'v1.10.0')
export 'src/math/random_fallback.dart';
export 'src/math/solve_cubic.dart';
export 'src/math/solve_quadratic.dart';
```